# Answer to "Machen Sie es gut"

Tags: usage

Sometimes when saying goodbye people would say

> Machen Sie es gut.

or

> Mach es gut.

What would be good answers to this? I can think of

> Gleichfalls.
>
> Sie auch. / Du auch.

Comment: I often respond with "Mach es besser", which I guess isn't very common though.

Comment: I don't think this is a phrase you should use when addressing someone formally.

Comment: Whenever you use imperative case, you can omit the conjugation of 'du' and the word 'du'. For eg: Instead of *Machst du das schnell* you can say "*Mach das schnell*"

Comment: @Em1 To which I often respond "Aber nicht zu oft", which is trying to be funny without being actually funny.

Comment: @Frankenstein: *can* sounds a bit weak here; the word "du" *has* to be omitted. "Machst du das schnell" is simply not a correct imperative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion, the best answer is your last choice - 
"Sie auch. / Du auch."

"Gleichfalls/Danke, Gleichfalls!" is more commonly used for things like "have a nice day/weekend" or "Viel Glück" etc.

Even if it should be "correct" and makes sense here, I have never head someone responding "Gleichfalls" to "Machs gut!"

And of course, as already said, simply saying "Danke" (or anything equal) is rude, as you imply you do not care if your opposite is having a good time or not - while he/she does.

Comment: Well, it's not always rude to just say "danke" - for example, when you add a friendly nodding or express reciprocation with other gestures.

Comment: @Carlster I would always say that it is rude. You are "taking" their wishes without "granting" them the same. Expressing you are happy/friendly/thankful for that does not change the fact imho.

Comment: Alternativ zu "Gleichfalls" wird auch "Ebenso" verwendet.

Comment: Actually, I often use gleichfalls in that case.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, these are good choices. A simple "Danke" in addition might not be amiss.